# Link to libraries built by GCC when I use ICC for my code

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, linker, icc

For a personal project on Linux, I would like to use ICC. My project uses Boost, Qt and several other libraries. These libraries are available on Ubuntu repository so I would like to save time by installing these prebuilt ones.

Is it possible for me to link dynamically my ICC-built executable with the libraries built by GCC?

Comment: This depends on the compiler flags used. Icc can do some non-portable things.  See the [Wikipedia article on ICC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_Compiler#Languages); then Google "ICC Gcc compatibility" for reports of other's experiences.  In general, there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible.  It may not be the safest thing ever, and I wonder why you want to use ICC for a personal project, but it could be OK, and you can use tools like valgrind to help you detect issues at run time for extra peace of mind.

Comment: because ICC is free for non-commercial project under Linux.

Comment: Sure, it's free.  So is GCC.  I was curious why you wanted to use ICC over GCC.

Comment: I want to use ICC because it allows me to better use their free (for personal project) Intel Parallel Studio XE.